# MakeFile not compiling and building .o file

Tags: c, makefile

When I type in "make" in the terminal to compile, I get en error message:

```
gcc  -c -Wall -std=c99 a2lib.c -o a2lib.o -lm
gcc  -g -std=c99 assign2.o a2lib.o -o assign2
gcc: error: assign2.o: No such file or directory
make: *** [assign2] Error 1
```

I have an `a2lib.h`, `a2lib.c`, and `assign2.c` file written. The `a2lib.c` and `assign2.c` both have `#include "a2lib.h"` and `#include <math.h>` and `#include <stdio.h>`.

In the `Makefile` I wrote, I have:

```
all: assign2

CC = gcc #Declaring new variable CC to replace gcc
#Compiling process

# Link
assign2: assign2.o a2lib.o
    $(CC) -g -std=c99 assign2.o a2lib.o -o assign2

# Compile
%.o: %.c
    $(CC) -c -Wall -std=c99 $< -o $@ -lm


assign2.o: a2lib.h

#Defining a dependency for assign2.o

a2lib.o: a2lib.h

#Defining a dependency for a2lib.o

.PHONY: all clean

#Declaring the PHONY targets

clean:
    rm assign2 assign2.o a2lib.o
```

I'm just not sure at all why `assign2.o` is not being created. When I type in `ls` to view the directories, `assign2.o` is not there but `a2lib.o` is there. So, `a2lib.o` is being created but `assign2.o` is not. There are no bugs in the C code in `assign2.c` either so I'm assuming something is wrong with the code in my `Makefile`. I'm not sure why.

Comment: I presume there's an `assign2.c` in your project directory?

Comment: have you tried a make assign2.o just to see it works?

Comment: Yes. I have assign2.c, a2lib.c, a2lib.h, and Makefile in the directory

Comment: when I do "make assign2.o", it says: 'assign2.o' is up to date. which i'm confused about since it isn't even created

Comment: What does `make -d assign2.o` output? (It will be a fair amount of lines.)

Comment: Considering target file `assign2.o'.
 File `assign2.o' does not exist.
  Considering target file `a2lib.h'.
   Looking for an implicit rule for `a2lib.h'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem `a2lib.h'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite `a2lib.h,v'.
    `RCS/a2lib.h'.
   
   No implicit rule found for `a2lib.h'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file `a2lib.h'.
  No need to remake target `a2lib.h'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file `assign2.o'.
Must remake target `assign2.o'.
Successfully remade target file `assign2.o'.
make: `assign2.o' is up to date.

Comment: It's much longer than that though. That's just the last chunk of it

Answer (score 0):

I can reproduce your problem if the `VPATH` environment variable is set (exported in the shell) and contains a directory where `assign2.o` exists.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/General-Search.html for an explanation about VPATH.

**Update:** My first answer lacked a solution. Type the following command in the shell before running make:

```
unset VPATH
```

If you want to see what value is currently assigned to `VPATH`, type

```
echo $VPATH
```

`VPATH` may be defined globally in some shell init script such as `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile` or their system wide equivalent.

Comment: So I should create a VPATH? Where would it lead to though if assign2.o isn't even being built?

Comment: I suspect you already have a `VPATH` set somewhere. Does `echo $VPATH` shows something? If so, type `unset VPATH` to undefine it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the following lines in your `makefile`:

```
assign2.o: a2lib.h

#Defining a dependency for assign2.o

a2lib.o: a2lib.h

#Defining a dependency for a2lib.o
```

to

```
assign2.o: a2lib.h  assign2.c

#Defining a dependency for assign2.o.
#Watch for changes in the source file too

a2lib.o: a2lib.h a2lib.c

#Defining a dependency for a2lib.o
#Watch for changes in the source file too
```

With this changes, `make` checks if there are changes in the sourcefile. Previously it only considered changes in the header to trigger a rebuild of the object file.